# why chrome developer tool showing "one" underscore?

Tags: html, css, web, bem

[image]

As one can see in above screenshot. In right side , Chrome developer tool,the highlighted portion showing "one" underscore .
But I used "two" underscore" in my `VScode` as you can see in left
{I am using here BEM methodology in `CSS`}

Comment: Check your HTML, the problem is there, not in your sass file.

Comment: Left is the CSS and on the right the HTML. There is probably just one underscore in your HTML source

Comment: Your HTML has two underscores in most of the adjacent divs but just one in this div so it is just a typo in your HTML - nothing to do with your CSS which correctly has two underscores like its adjacent stylings.

Comment: yeah ! It solved , thansk for help.